# Switch between activities after login

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I switch between 2 activities after login ?

After login I can go to:
DashboardUserActivity
DashboardProActivity

Now I am creating an empty DashboardActivity that open the right Dashboard but in my opinion this solution not is really good.

This is an example:

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (type == USER) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, DashboardUserActivity.class));
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, DashboardProActivity.class));
        }

        finish();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create any empty Dashboard activity. on the login screen itself, when login is success, you can add intent to the type of activity you want to launch(user Dashboard or Pro Dashboard).

Comment: Yes, I know it but I have about 4 sections (login, signup, verify_account...) where I need to call and open a Dashboard. For this reason I want call only 1 time a Dashboard and in only one point, manage the switch.

Comment: otherwise I need to write "if...else" in each of these sections and I don't like duplicate the code. Another solution is create an Utility class that switch activity

Comment: yes, if you have about 4 sections then there will be lot of redundancy in the code.you can use only one utility class

Comment: ok, thanks. If there are not other good solutions, I will create an utility to switch

Comment: Yes, IMO this is the solution you should go for.